# Why is the unchangable Nintendo Game Boy logo in the cartridge?

Tags: game-boy

According to Gameboy [sic] Development Wiki page [The Cartridge Header](https://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/The_Cartridge_Header#0104-0133_-_Nintendo_Logo), locations 0x104 through 0x133 in the cartridge contain a bitmap of the Nintendo logo that's displayed when the Game Boy is turned on. (Presumably that's the "Nintendo®" text/logo [shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Fh9SpWFdn0).) After booting and displaying the logo, these data are checked by the GB (the first 0x18 bytes on the Color Game Boy and all 0x30 bytes on other models) and, if the data are different from what's expected, the unit locks up.

The Game Boy has internal ROM used during the [boot process](https://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/Power_Up_Sequence) that reads the cartridge header, and according to that document a copy of the image is stored there (though perhaps it's only a partial copy in the case of the Color Game Boy). What are the reasons for storing this image (or a copy of it) in the cartridge?

One thought that comes to mind is that this is a licensing protection mechanism: the logo is intellectual property protectable under trademark laws and the specific binary representation of it under copyright laws, allowing Nintendo to sue anybody manufacturing working cartridges without a license from them. If this is the reason, references confirming this and discussion of its relationship to other licensing protection mechanisms would be appreciated.

However, Nintendo already had a seemingly more powerful version of this in the [10NES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIC_(Nintendo)) chip, so why wouldn't they just use that? (It was eventually [successfully used to enforce cartridge licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_Games_Corp._v._Nintendo_of_America_Inc.), though Nintendo couldn't have known this would succeed in court when the Game Boy was being designed.)

Comment: There’s an interesting conference made by a GameBoy developer where he explain this fact as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyzD8pNlpwI

Comment: It might be worth bearing in mind that this is the same Nintendo that included a lock-out chip in its NES systems (and subsequent consoles) to stop others from releasing software for those platforms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Summary/TLDR

From court documents it's clear that the primary purpose of a similar
technique used by Sega starting at least as early as 1988 (released
while the Game Boy was still under development) was to use trademark
law to stop distribution of original games by other developers without
a license from the console manufacturer. Nintendo had been dealing
with the same problems, possibly for longer than Sega had, and no
doubt had lawyers and managers who were just as smart and competent,
so it's likely they did it for the same reasons.

#### Sega's TMSS and its Purpose

As [mentioned by Kaz in a comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11736/7208#comment36256_11747), in 1990 (a year after the
release of the GameBoy) Sega started doing the same thing with their
[TradeMark Security System](https://segaretro.org/TradeMark_Security_System) on the Genesis III. This was a great
clue, as it turns out to lead to fairly compelling evidence about why
they did this.

According to [977 F. 2d 1510 - Sega Enterprises Ltd v. Accolade
Inc](https://openjurist.org/977/f2d/1510) ¶6:

> ...Sega had grown concerned about the rise of software and hardware
> piracy in Taiwan and other Southeast Asian countries to which it
> exported its products. Taiwan is not a signatory to the Berne
> Convention and does not recognize foreign copyrights. Taiwan does
> allow prosecution of trademark counterfeiters. However, the
> counterfeiters had discovered how to modify Sega's game programs to
> blank out the screen display of Sega's trademark before repackaging
> and reselling the games as their own.

It's made clear in ¶79 that this was a conscious and explicit decision
by Sega:

> ...Sega officials testified that Sega incorporated the TMSS into the
> Genesis console, known in Asia as the Mega-Drive, in order to lay
> the groundwork for the trademark prosecution of software pirates who
> sell counterfeit cartridges in Taiwan and South Korea, as well as in
> the United States.

It seems also that the system had been designed and implemented in
cartridges before the first release of the Genesis system in 1988, as
would obviously have been necessary if the old cartridges were to work
in the Genesis III. ¶8:

> During the reverse engineering process, Accolade engineers had
> discovered a small segment of code—the TMSS initialization code—that
> was included in the "power-up" sequence of every Sega game, but that
> had no identifiable function. The games would operate on the
> original Genesis console even if the code segment was removed.

(Accolade instructed their developers to include this initialization
code in all their games, too, though at the time they didn't know the
purpose of it, and all their ran fine on the Genesis III except for
one, *Onslaught*, where the developer didn't do this right.)

While this is in Taiwan solving a much more serious problem than
unlicensed cartridges from other software developers—copyright
couldn't protect direct copies of the vendors' original games—SEGA at
least admitted that this was intended to be used in the U.S. as well
(see above), where it wasn't necessary to protect Sega's first-party
game cartridges as they were already well protected by copyright.

Nintendo had to deal with the same IP issues for home video game
consoles as Sega did, and had possibly been dealing with them for
longer. The NES, released in 1985 (three years before the Genesis) had
already implemented technical measures to prevent use of unlicensed
cartridges, probably due to bad experience with the lack of a lockout
system in the Famicom.

Nintendo's lawyers and managers were doubtless as smart and competent
as Sega's, so it's no surprise that they might come up with a similar
solution to the problem. Nintendo's solution might even be legally
slightly stronger than Sega's solution because rather than just a
short code (`SEGA`) in the cartridge triggering trademark display, the
actual trademarked image was in the cartridge.

#### Actual Effectiveness of the Measure

It would be interesting to know if this was ever tested in Taiwanese
courts. A few years later Sega [sued an infringer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sega_v._Accolade) in the United
States where this was brought up as part of the case, but on appeal it
was found allowable for third parties to trigger the trademark display
where necessary for compatibility [¶1](https://openjurist.org/977/f2d/1510):

> The question is whether the computer manufacturer may enjoin
> competing cartridge manufacturers from gaining access to its
> computers through the use of the code on the ground that such use
> will result in the display of a "false" trademark. Again, our
> holding is based on the public policies underlying the statute. We
> hold that when there is no other method of access to the computer
> that is known or readily available to rival cartridge manufacturers,
> the use of the initialization code by a rival does not violate the
> [Lanham Trademark] Act even though that use triggers a misleading
> trademark display.

The more detailed reasoning given in ¶73 et seq. makes it *really*
clear that it's Sega's fault the trademark was displayed when
Accolade's game was started and it was entirely on Sega to fix this.

> Because the TMSS has the effect of regulating access to the Genesis
> III console, and because there is no indication in the record of any
> public or industry awareness of any feasible alternate method of
> gaining access to the Genesis III, we hold that Sega is primarily
> responsible for any resultant confusion.
>
> ...while it may not have been Sega's ultimate goal to mislabel
> Accolade's products, the record is clear that the false labeling was
> the result of a deliberate decision on the part of Sega to include
> in the Genesis III a device which would both limit general access
> and cause false labeling. [This] compels us to place primary
> responsibility for consumer confusion squarely on Sega.

This is a slightly different situation from the Nintendo Game Boy one,
since, as noted above, the Game Boy carts must actually *contain* the
trademark, rather than just *triggering* display of it. But the
principle seems to me to hold: the actual display of the trademark is
done by Nintendo code, having the correct material on the cartridge to
trigger that is necessary for the game to play, and were it not for
Nintendo's code the end user wouldn't be seeing Nintendo's trademark.

As a side note, Accolade had also needed to disassemble and
reverse-engineer Sega games to figure out how to overcomes TMSS, and
this involved making (internal) copies of the code. This was found to
be legal as a fair use when no other means could serve to understand
the (non-copyrightable) functionality of the program ([¶31 et seq.,
ibid.](https://openjurist.org/977/f2d/1510)), consistent with the earlier [Atari Games Corp. v.
Nintendo of America Inc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_Games_Corp._v._Nintendo_of_America_Inc.) suit. (Atari lost that one not because
of their reverse-engineering, but because of copyright violations due
to also copying original Nintendo source code.)

This and various other comments in the decision make it pretty clear
that the judge felt (at that point in time) that it was perfectly
legal to do whatever you needed to do to make your software run on any
computer you liked. Ah; the good old days; new legislation would
change that before the end of the decade.

#### Current Day

All this is probably purely historical now.

The above decision regarding use of trademarks when required to run
software on a computer probably no longer holds in this age of the
[DMCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) where that check would be argued to be an ["effective
technological measure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-circumvention) restricting use of the computer.

Taiwan (as "Chinese Taipei") became a signatory to the Berne
convention on 2002-01-01.

Comment: In some other venues such as guitar design, courts have held that trademarks can generally be applied only to *non-functional* aspects of a product.  A company can't trademark the physical shape of parts of a guitar that are designed to be held or manipulated, or that would rest against the player's body, but they may trademark (and do aggressively protect) the shapes of portions, such as the headstock, which would not be used in such fashion.  If a cartridge wouldn't function at all without a particular bit pattern in ROM, such a bit pattern should not be trademarkable, but ...

Comment: ...if e.g. the cartridge were to validate the contents of a subset of pixels that would make it hard to make anything that didn't look like either the Nintendo logo or a broken version thereof, I think trademark protection might have been enforceable against a company that opted to use a non-broken-looking Nintendo logo rather than showing a broken logo but playing anyway.

Comment: @supercat Well, that's interesting speculation, but simply that; these things are decided by judges, not by bystanders. I personally doubt that, once you're displaying something that looks enough like the Nintendo logo for people to think, "that looks like a Nintendo logo" you're in the same position as if you'd displayed a more accurate version; trademark recognition by the general public is what trademark law is all about, after all.

Comment: That leads me to believe a judge might say, "approximate, exact: it doesn't matter; it would be a trademark violation if not technically required, and once it is technicically required it doesn't matter if the logo is more or less accurate." But again, this is simply idle speculation, of no use to anybody without a judgement to reference.

Comment: My point was that if the company is given the choice to display a broken-looking logo or a trademarked one and opts for the latter, the "technical requirement" defense would be less likely to fly if displaying a broken logo would not otherwise interfere with gameplay.

Comment: @supercat I understand your point; I simply disagree based on my understanding of the purpose of trademark law. If the broken-looking logo is still clearly identifiable by the consumer as the logo, it's just as much of a trademark violation as a non-broken logo, since it's still "a recognizable sign, design, or expression which identifies products or services of a particular source."[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark)].

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear that the logo wouldn't be recognizable as a broken-looking Nintendo logo so much as it would appear to be a broken garbled mess.  By way of analogy, suppose one were to take a picture of the Eiffel Tower and super-imposed a chess board, and blanked about 90% of the squares.  The ironwork details that remained may not be particular identifiable as the Eiffel Tower, but it may be hard to come up with any other picture that would "fit".

Comment: @supercat No, that wasn't clear at all to me. You originally said that the choices were to look like "the Nintendo logo or a broken version thereof"; so I guess what you really wanted for the latter choice was instead "doesn't look like a broken version of the Nintendo logo"?

Comment: Looking at the technical merits of trademarking a ROM representation of an image, it should be pointed out that data in ROM are not an image unless rendered as such, and for any given ROM data there is a set (in fact an infinite set) of rendering algorithms that would result in the image in question, or indeed any other image.

Comment: @Frog The data in the ROM are not trademarked; the trademark violation occurs when you program the Game Boy to display the trademarked logo. In this case, you displayed it by putting a specific sequence of bytes in the cartridge ROM that a program in the boot ROM displays as an image, but had you done it in a different way, e.g. by including your own program in the cartridge ROM that displayed different data as the logo, you'd still be violating the trademark. The Game Boy's impelementation can be worked around; see [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18319/7208).

Comment: @cjs it would seem that it’s a combination of the ROM data and Nintendo’s code that render the image on the screen.  Reductio ad absurdism is that the cartridge provides a single bit to tell the Nintendo code to do so.  In this case it’s clear that the particular bit pattern is necessarily there to allow the program to run, which would not violate trademark.  However, this is not a court of law and so that judgement is ultimately made elsewhere.

Comment: If you force people to display your trademark to accomplish a particular functional result, you can't them complain that they displayed your trademark. That's the very opposite of how trademark law works -- you have to diligently protect it from abuse, not require people to abuse it. You can't complain about a trademark violation that you deliberately encouraged.

Comment: @Frog You are switching between several topics here. I already make it quite clear in my post above that what would normally be considered a trademark violation is not when it's required for the operation of the system, even quoting the judge on this. (I'm glad to see that both you and @ David agree with me on this.) That doesn't change the separate issue that, absent a functional need, displaying those data from the ROM to produce a trademark image would be a trademark violation, absent other mitigating circumstances.

Comment: @cjs key here is that the cartridge code doesn’t render the image, this is done by Nintendo’s firmware and so the case could be made that there is no violation.  Objectively the truth lies somewhere in between, but legally it’s down to who has the better lawyer.

Comment: @Frog No, that is not the key at all. (This may be a subtle point to some.) The programmer deliberate instructed the machine to produce the logo. The reason this is not a trademark violation (though it normally would be) is because if you don't do so, _other functionality is disabled_.

Comment: To be clear though, as I understand the firmware built into the console (i.e. Nintendo’s) does the rendering and so Nintendo’s programmers instructed the machine to produce the logo.  Therefore there would be no trademark violation whether or not functionality was disabled.

Comment: @Frog No. Nintendo's code produces the logo only if specific code in the cartridge contains an image of the logo. Were it not for other things, different logos could be included in the cartridge and displayed. (But even were it not an actual image in the cartridge, a cart calling a system-supplied function that produces the logo on its own, without the authors being authorized by Nintendo to call that function,  would still be a trademark violation if it did not also disable other essential functionality.

Comment: Nintendo’s code produces the logo only if a specific *bit pattern* is present, it’s not an image until it’s rendered.  I don’t see how calling a function without authorisation can be a trademark violation.

Comment: @Frog Yes, I understand you don't see. But all the law cares about is if your actions caused to be produced a trademark viewed by the user; it does not matter _how_you do it. It matters not wWhether it's instructing a game console to do it through any of various means, instructing a web browser to render a PNG image, or printing it on a piece of paper. If you have a choice to write/call or not the "produce trademark image" code, no matter how simple or complex, you must have authorization from the trademark owner or you will be violating the trademark.

Comment: And as a side note, though more relevant to copyright, generally that bit pattern _would_ be considered "the image," in the same way that if you download an MP4 file containing a movie that's considered "the movie" just as much as a reel of film or a videotape containing the movie. Isomorphic transformations that put something into a different digital "form" do not change what the content is for the purposes of Intellectual Property laws. (However, displaying it differently would make a difference for trademarks, unless the user looked at a hex dump and immediately thought, "Ah, Nintendo!")

Comment: @Frog At any rate, if you want to discuss this further or get further information on it, I'd suggest you formulate a question for the [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/), where people will be able to describe in much greater detail why calling a function can result in a trademark violation and the like.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz And if you are rich enough.. you might prevail in such a lawsuit... But Nintendo is very rich.

Answer (score 14):

> According to Gameboy [sic] Development Wiki page The Cartridge Header, locations 0x104 through 0x133 in the cartridge contain a bitmap of the Nintendo logo that's displayed when the Game Boy is turned on. (Presumably that's the "Nintendo®" text/logo shown in this video.) After booting and displaying the logo, these data are checked by the GB (the first 0x18 bytes on the Color Game Boy and all 0x30 bytes on other models) and, if the data are different from what's expected, the unit locks up.

Describes the boot process in general - maybe it is good to consider that displaying the logo already is most of the boot process. After all, it's a game system, all useful initialization will be done by the game itself.

> Clearly the Game Boy has internal ROM available at least during the boot process so that it can do system setup and read the cartridge header.

It's a 256 byte on-chip ROM. Not exactly a luxurious environment. More than 5/8th are already occupied with displaying the logo. The ROM is present at address 0000h - which makes sense for a Z80, doesn't it?

> It seems to me that the image above could just as easily be stored there (though it looks like it's not).

Well, it is. Occupying address 00A8h...00DFh.

The decision, to use the one in the cartridge (Adress 0104h) instead of the Boot-ROM copy (at 00A8h), may look arbitrary at first, but as a second thought, it reveals that this will be quite handy when such a cartridge is inserted, as the user will not see the Nintendo logic when the game locks up, but whatever foreign is stored there, thus **making sure the blame is directed** at them.

> What are the reasons for storing this image (or a copy of it) in the cartridge?

I'd say it's a simple copy protection mechanism.

> One thought that comes to mind is that this is a licensing protection mechanism: the logo is intellectual property protectable under trademark laws and the specific binary representation of it under copyright laws, allowing Nintendo to sue anybody manufacturing working cartridges without a license from them.

I guess that's exactly the intention - giving lawyers a leverage for the time there is a need to sue, while avoiding upfront cost of (ultimate broken) hardware based copy protection schemes.

Important in this context is that they not just required some location to read Nintendo (like [Kaz mentioned](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11736/why-is-the-unchangable-nintendo-game-boy-logo-in-the-cartridge/11747?noredirect=1#comment36256_11747) with the [Sega TMSS scheme](https://segaretro.org/TradeMark_Security_System)), but hold a graphic image. Graphic images registered as trademark, even if it's 'just' the name, bear a higher degree of protection than a name represented as (ASCII) characters. While a trademarked name can be used in many ways in every day life, graphic trademarks can not.

> However, Nintendo already had a seemingly more powerful version of this in the 10NES chip,

Not more powerful, but a total different tool. The image within the Game Boy code was intended to use the very strong trademark law against any (worthwhile) attempt to create compatible software. The CIC was meant as a copy protection device stopping any attempt to build cartridges without licencing (and buying the chip). And copyright was only used in addition in case someone did go all the length to reverse engineer it.

> so why wouldn't they just use that?

Simply cost. The game boy was meant to be as cheap as possible (*1). It's start introduction price was less than 90 USD - half of what the NES was. Similar Game Boy games were lower priced than NES games. Using the CIC would have meant to add that chip not only to every GB, but also each and every cartridge. All increasing cost without a direct benefit.

---

*1 - One reason why it got that in 1989 already outdated B&W screen instead of state of the art colour (like the Lynx).

Comment: Another helpful result of displaying the logo from the cartridge ROM instead of the boot ROM is that contact issues on data lines could be easily spotted as vertical lines in the logo.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher That's interesting enough that you ought to make it an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: Sega appeared to have done something similar with the Mega Drive (Genesis): https://segaretro.org/TMSS

Comment: @Kaz Seams quite like it.

Comment: @Kaz TMSS, and especially the resulting [Sega v. Accolade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sega_v._Accolade) case, is clear evidence that the industry knew about and was using this as a technique to enforce licensing. I think this could be expanded into a worthwhile answer.

Answer (score 5):

I completely agree to the answer provided by Raffzahn, but there is an additional perceived advantage of using the logo from the cartridge. The contact between the cartridge and the slot known for its suboptimal reliability (and created the impression that blowing into the cartridge to de-dust it helps). If reading the ROM is unreliable, the Logo on the screen is displayed in a garbled fashion, like containing vertical lines if data lines are stuck high or even complete noise if some high address lines fail to address the logo area at all. This helps indicating to the user that the cartridge connection is unreliable and the reason for the game to not boot.

Answer (score 4):

The Nintendo logo thing is a working and legal trademark security system.

Sega messed up with their Trademark Security System, because it doesn't actually include the logo in the cart binary.

Nintendo did it right.

Any unlicensed cart that has that Nintendo logo bitmap in it is truly violating the trademark if the logo shows on the screen.  But if the logo isn't there, it won't run on a real gameboy.  Therefore, those who make working unlicensed games that show the Nintendo logo can be prosecuted for trademark infringement.

Because the one in the cartridge is what's shown, it IS expressive data, and not just stuff to make the game work. And that legal distinction is what made Nintendo's trademark security system work, when Sega's was overturned on appeal.

That said, a cart that temporarily swaps the logo in when it's tested, but then swaps it back out when it's displayed does NOT violate trademarks. And this is indeed possible on the Gameboy. It tests, THEN copies to video memory.  If it copied to memory, THEN tested, then displayed it out of memory, then this dodge wouldn't work.

Another method is a passthrough cart. you plug your legit game into the cart slot in your unlicensed game to get past the TMSS. A super nes game actually did this as I recall.

This is also why PSOnes won't play imports. because they actually verify the black screen logo design stored in the image, and that it states the correct territory.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the 10NES chip, it proved ineffective. Eventually ways were found to disable or bypass it. Mostly that involved a circuit in the cartridge using a voltage spike to cause the 10NES chip to latch up and stop working temporarily.

However, where it was somewhat effective was when it was cloned. Tengen, a subsidiary of Atari, cloned the 10NES chip by obtaining the source code from the Copyright Office under false pretences. Nintendo sued and eventually won in court, due to the copyright infringement.

This told Nintendo two things. Firstly, having a separate chip for copy protection was unlikely to work as it could be interfered with in the same way as 10NES was, and simply added cost to the system. So the Gameboy instead moved the protection to an on-die ROM that was part of the CPU, which make it extremely difficult to circumvent. In fact, it resisted attempts to read it until decades later, and the method used (clock glitching) was not something that a cartridge could do reliably itself.

Secondly, copyright and trademark law were more effective at deterring unlicensed games. Making the cartridge check look for the copyrighted and trademarked Nintendo logo graphic, which was then forced to be displayed on screen (similar to how Sega displayed "produced by or under licence from Sega" on some of their systems). If anyone copied the logo without authorization, Nintendo could sue them and have a very good chance of winning.

Comment: The information about the technical failure of 10NES sounds good, but do you have dates for it? The Game Boy was released in April 1989; were successful exploits of 10GEN known to Nintendo in 1988?

Comment: As for copyright and trademark law being more effective, I don't know if Nintendo knew that in 1988 when they were developing the Game Boy. It was before any of the suits I'm aware of, such as suit against Atari/Tengen over the 10NES clone. (["Nintendo filed no infringement action against Atari until November 1989."](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/F2/975/832/163650/)) Can you rough out a timeline for what Nintendo knew when about copy protection chips vs. trademark protection?

Comment: According to "Bible Adventures: Boss Fight Books #7" the voltage spike technique was known in at least 1987, probably earlier in Taiwan where it was apparently discovered. Also, Tengen released Pac-Man in 1988, which I think was one of the first to use their Rabbit chip cloned from the 10NES source.

Comment: I'd say it's likely that Nintendo were aware of the limitations of the 10NES chip at that time. They appeared to be hedging their bets, having filed the source code with the Copyright Office rather than keeping it secret like they did with the Gameboy ROM.

Comment: Wouldn't the source code have been filed by the time the 10NES was first released, before anybody had figured out how to compromise it? At that point they couldn't know the effectiveness of IP versus technical protections, though of course it's reasonable that they were going for both with the 10NES, and decided to abandon the technical protection due to known exploits by the time they were finishing up the Game Boy design. Ironically enough, within five years or so their attempt at IP protection [had also failed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sega_v._Accolade).

Comment: Also, a side point: the Game Boy boot ROM was first extracted in 2003 via [decapping and reading the bits](http://dot-matrix-game.blogspot.com/2014/01/boot-roms.html), which was [exactly what Atari had done with the 10NES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_Games_Corp._v._Nintendo_of_America_Inc.#Fair_Use_Defense_of_Reverse_Engineering) (as well as separately getting the source code). The delay with the GB as compared to the 10NES appears to have been simply that nobody with the resources and interest to do it for the GB came along until 2003, though it could have been done much earlier.

Comment: I can't find a date for the filing of the source code. But I think it very likely that they were continually improving their copy protection mechanisms, and would have been aware of some of the limitations of the 10NES chip.